# Member-Parent Awareness

Tags: c#, matrix, collections, delegates

I am presently working on a structure for representing objects 2 dimensionally (in a grid) such that they can be described and interacted based on their relationships to each other. At present it works as follows:

- Matrix is the collection itself. I consists of a list of type T which contains the raw data being organized
- List of MatrixItem of type T, which are the members of the Matrix and store their own position as well as the data which is being organized
- Its maximum X and Y dimensions
- The Maximum number of members it can contain
- The number of members it currently contains

So, my problem arises in trying to make all of the grid items aware of each other, which is the entire purpose of the Matrix, a collection in which members are aware of each other by position. My original thought was to put a Top, Bottom, Left, and Right, neighbor in each of the items and store its neighbors inside each member. But that doesn't work because they are individual instances and don't effect the original object. My next plan was to have an update mechanic where when one was updated, its neighbors all updated their definitions and when a grid updated its neighbor, the original would update. But that doesn't work because they infinitely update each other, and stack overflow.

The next plan was to pass references of the MatrixItem into all of its neighbors, and then each item could simply reference each other. That doesn't work because I don't know how to make a property be a reference to another object, and getting and setting that property would dynamically get or set another object, which would be defined at instantiation.

My last hope is to make all of the children able to trigger a method in the Matrix, but I need to make it available to the children. Is this what delegates are for, and if so how do I implement them in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. You actually had a few good attempts - For example, you can add a property to your MatrixItem, which contains the whole Matrix - it'll be a reference automatically, so if you update the list at any point all the others will be updated - but you have to make sure to initialize all items with the same Matrix list:

```
//your Matrix list is called matrix
for (var i = 0; i < matrix.MaxLength; i++)
    matrix.Add (new MatrixItem (foo, otherProperty, matrix));
```

Another possible solution *would* be to let each item know what it's neighbour is - because the neighbour would know his neighbour as well, so you could recursively get all items of the Matrix:

```
var lastMatrixItem = new MatrixItem (foo, otherProperty, null, null);
matrix.add (lastMatrixItem);
for (var i = 1; i < matrix.MaxLength; i++)
{
    var newMatrixItem = new MatrixItem (foo, otherProperty, lastMatrixItem, null);
    lastMatrixItem.followingItem = newMatrixItem;
    matrix.Add (newMatrixItem);
    lastMatrixItem = newMatrixItem;
}
```

But this is a little bit confusing if you're not familiar with references.

Actually it would even be possible to update all Matrix knowledges of the MatrixItem, as you mentioned:

> My next plan was to have an update mechanic where when one was updated, its neigbours all updated their definitions and when a grid updated its neighbour, the original would update.

You'd simply have to add guards. That means, you'd have to check wether the value assigned to the property is actually different to the old value, and only if so, update the property. Then the updater functions of the other items would only be called, if the value was new, so it wouldn't result in an infinite loop.

An example:

```
public class Item
{
    private int _id;
    public Item Child;
    public Item Parent;

    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set
        {
            if (_id == value) //this is the guard
                return;
            _id = value;
            if (Child != null)
                Child.Id = _id;
            if (Parent != null)
                Parent.Id = _id;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() =>
        $"Id: {Id} child: ({Child?.ToString() ?? "-"})";
}
```

If the guard wouldn't exist, a StackOverflow exception occurrs, as an endless loop is built. With the class above, this is possible:

[image: This is a use of the class in the interactive]

Actually I used the class in the interactive, to demonstrate it.

Without the guard it wouldn't work:

[image: This is the use of the Class without the guard in the interactive]

(the reason for the i being marked as an error is that the interactive resets itself after a StackOverflow exception)

Comment: So, by guard you mean something like in depth first cell generation where after its been updated its considered "visited" and it reaches all from the original point by back stepping

Comment: @Azeranth I updated my answer, in the hope to clarify guards.

Comment: @Azeranth is everything clear now? Then please mark the answer as an answer, so that the topic is closed.